# How do I compare two text files with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, shoulda

I have a method which compares if two text files have the same content.

How do I compare if two text files have the same content using RSpec?

Comment: What does your current method look like?  You say you have a method that does 'x' so please do show your code.

Comment: See http://sscce.org/. You need to show code, sample data and any errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On a trivial level:

```
IO.read(file1).should == IO.read(file2)
```

If you want to do something nicer, you're likely going to need to write a new matcher, something like `have_same_content_as` defined to check for the above condition. "[Up and Running with Custom RSpec Matchers](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/10/up-and-running-with-custom-rspec-matchers)" is a nice tutorial on writing custom matchers.

Comment: @Dom: I found it elsewhere and fixed the link.

Answer (score 15):

For others who stumble across this, check the FileUtils#cmp method:

```
require 'fileutils'
expect(FileUtils.compare_file(file1, file2)).to be_truthy
```